# Jquery AJAX methods

Tags: jquery

I have searched on here for some time and can't find a specific answer to a simple issue.

I have some generated HTML which includes links to files which may or may not exist on the server. The generator doesn't know if the files exist or not so it assumes they do.

I'm trying to use the JQ AJAX methods to check for the broken href's and `hide()` the link if the file is non-existent, should be simple enough I think.

```
<tr>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>201106</td>
    <td>PRODID</td>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>98</td>
    <td>40.95</td>
    <td>4013.1</td>
    <td>15.56365</td>
    <td>2487.8623</td>
    <td>61.99</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="9" style="border-top:#047D66 solid 1px; background-color:#e0e0e0; border-bottom:#047D66 solid 1px"><br></td>
    <td><a href="http://dashboards/wrappedstuff_uk/files/PRODID.pdf" id="checklnk">PDF</a></td>
</tr>
```

My Jquery script

```
$.ajax({
    url: $('#checklnk').attr('href'),
    type: 'text',
    method: 'HEAD',
    error: function() {
        $(this).hide();
    },
    success: function(){
        $(this).css('background-image',url('/dashboards/cms/intra/images/icon-link-pdf.png'));
    }
});
```

The links are not hidden and I suspect the problem might be that `$(this)` is not the DOM element I expect.

Anyone like to point me in the right direction.

Comment: When are you running that code? In a loop on DOM ready? When the user clicks an element?

Comment: do you have more a tags ? If you should use classes for that.

Comment: How does the table have any relevence to your `#checklink`? Some more explanation will be needed here.

Comment: I haven't heard about `method:HEAD`. what is this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You guessed it right `$(this)` doesn't refer to the `href`, you will need to use element id to do your stuff. Something like this

```
$("#checklnk").hide();
```

OR

Check all anchor tags on the page in one shot

```
 $("a").each(function(i){
      $.ajax({
          url: $(this).attr('href'),
          type: 'text',
          method: 'HEAD',
          error: function() {
                $(this).hide();
          },
          success: function(){
                $(this).css('background-image',url('/dashboards/cms/intra/images/icon-link-pdf.png'));
          }
      });        
  });
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({
  url:$('#checklnk').attr('href'),
  type: 'text',
  method: 'HEAD',
  error: function() {
    $("#checklnk").hide();
  },
  success: function(){
    $("#checklnk").css('background-image',url('/dashboards/cms/intra/images/icon-link-pdf.png'));
    }
```

success and error async methods. So you have to use selector again

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you save your `$(this)` to a variable before you do the `AJAX` Call.  So you have access to your specified link and your able to `.hide(), .show()` . Further if there are more a-elements in your html page, you should use classes instead of id's ! Short Example:

```
var myAnchor=$(this);

$.ajax({
    // run your code here.
});
```